# SSLStream throwing exception when moving to .NET 4.51

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

Previously in .NET 3.5 this code worked fine:

```
protected bool OpenSsl(string hostSslServer)
    {
        if ((this._enableSSL == false) || (this._isSSLOpen == true))
            return (true);

        this._isSSLOpen = false;

        this._sslConnectionStream = new SslStream(this._tcpSocket.GetStream(), false, new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(this.ValidateServerCertificate), null);
        this._sslConnectionStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostSslServer);
        this._sslProtocol = _sslConnectionStream.SslProtocol.ToString();        

        this._isSSLOpen = true;
        return (true);
    }
```

The line this._sslProtocol = _sslConnectionStream.SslProtocol.toString(); was designed to ascertain what protocol was being used. However since then I discovered that TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 aren't part of the SslProtocols enum in 3.5 so I switched the project over to 4.5. However now I have exceptions being thrown, specifically with the AuthenticateAsClient line. The exception is "A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception." The inner exception is "The message received was unexpected or badly formatted".

Since then I did some research and found that I can connect using this code:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection xc = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection();
        this._sslConnectionStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostSslServer, xc, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12, false);
```

That replaces the previous line with the call to AuthenticateAsClient. However the issue here is that with this code (which I have to admit I don't understand) I set the ssl protocol as one of the parameters. I don't want to do that. I want to know what ssl protocol the host is using that I am connecting to.

Is there any way around this?

Since then I changed the parameter for sslprotocols to this:

SslProtocols.Ssl2 | SslProtocols.Ssl3 | SslProtocols.Tls | SslProtocols.Tls11 | SslProtocols.Tls12

And am getting another exception thrown: "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm"

Comment: SslProtocols is a *flag*, you can set it to `SslProtocols.Tls11|SslProtocols.Tls12`. If the original overload which uses the `Default` option didn't work, it's because the server doesn't even allow TLS 1.0. It's not a bug in .NET, most likely there wa a change in the server

Comment: Ah! However now I am getting this error: "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm"

Answer (score 0):

I removed SSL2 from the list of protocols and it works.